# Searching for multiple attributes in a search index and returning the ones with the maximum attributes matched

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene

I am indexing records of type {name, start_date, end_date, status, user_id, object_id, attr1_id, attr2_id, attr3_id, attr4_id, attr5_id .....attr30_id} in ElasticSearch/Solr.

I want to search in this index for a set of these attributes like attr1_id, attr2_id, attrx_id, attry_id etc...
The cardinality of the attributes are different.

Is there some way to search and return only those results that matched the max number of attributes?
e.g.

```
row1 : attr1_id, attr2_id, attr3_id
row2 : attr1_id, attr2_id
row3 : attr1_id
row4 : attr2_id
row5 : attr3_id
row6 : attr6_id, attrx_id, attry_id
row7 : attr6_id
row8 : attrx_id
```

The result should be
row1 and row6 
as row1 is more exact match compared to rows 2,3,4,5.
Similarly row6 is more exactly matching compared to rows 7 and 8.

Is there a direct query to get this.
Currently I am returning all 8 rows and doing this in my application.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.